# Is there a way to add three registers together, in a single line of cod in MIPS architecture?

Tags: assembly, mips, computer-science, cpu-architecture, mars-simulator

It is clear that most add instructions has the syntax add $t0, $t1, $t2; which would add t1 and t2 together and store it in t0. However, is it possible to add three registers together and store it in one, in a single line of code? Ex; t0 = t1 + t2 + t3?

Comment: I suppose you could do `add $t0, $t1, $t2; add $t0, $t0, $t3`.  That's only line with two instructions.

Comment: See the [MIPS green card](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs61c/resources/MIPS_Green_Sheet.pdf) -- it has all the instruction MIPS has in a short two page form.  There's several kinds of add, as R-Type and as I-Type.  If something you want to do is not on this sheet, you have to break it into several instructions using what it does have.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Every source like has to correspond to a single machine instruction (or a pseudo-instruction the assemble expands for you).

Your expression has two `+` operations in it, and MIPS doesn't have a 3-input addition instruction.  The normal way would be to use two instructions, like this:

```
    addu   $t0, $t1, $t2    # t0 = t1 + t2
    addu   $t0, $t0, $t3    # t0 += t3
```

Assembly is *not* like high-level languages; it doesn't get *compiled*, it only gets *assembled* into machine code.  **What you can do in asm syntax is restricted by what the machine code can encode for a single instruction** for that ISA (in your case MIPS).

---

You *could* in theory have an assembler that allowed syntax like `addu dst, src1, src2, src3, ...` and expanded it to multiple `addu` machine instructions for you (like how `li $v0, 0x12345678` assembles to `lui`/`addiu`).  But AFAIK no MIPS assembler does that.

Comment: So, if I were to do; $t0 = $t1 + $t2 + $t3, I would have to store $t1 + $t2 in another register and add that to $t3, and finally store it in $t0? "  add $t4, $t1, $t2   " then " add $t0, $t4, $t3  "

Comment: @iYahoOu: you could do that, but there's no need to use a separate temporary, just use `$t0` for the `t1+t2` intermediate result.  Asm instructions read their inputs before writing their outputs so it's fine to use the same register as a source and destination in the same instruction.  Updated my answer.  You could also look at what a compiler does, e.g. on https://godbolt.org/.  Use `-O2` or at least `-Og` so the compiler doesn't store everything to memory.